# How to generate different ids using jquery for same class elements

Tags: jquery

Am having two `div`s with same `class` name so when am attaching an element by creating `id` for both the `div`s, am getting the element `id` name as same for both the elements in both `div`s.

Example:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="example" id="example_1">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="nav">
    <div class="example" id="example_2">
    </div>
</div>
```

and I have used `jquery` syntax as

```
 $(".nav").append(example)
```

where `example_i` increments.

How can I make different `id`s using `jquery`?

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.nav').each(function(i,v){


$(this).append('<div id=example_'+i+'>example_'+i+'</div>')//use index of each .nav index starts at zero so if you need to start at 1 add 1 to index

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">

</div>
<div class="nav">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this if you are not adding simple html strings. First make `example` a jQuery object, if it is not one already. Then you can easily manipulate the attributes.

```
var $example = $(example),
    idPre = 'example_',
    count = 1;
$(".nav").each(function() {
    $(this).append($example.clone().attr('id', idPre + count));
    count++;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplification of guradio's answer, [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) can also take a function which returns the element based on the current index. This avoids the extra `each()` loop and recreating `$(this)`.

```js
$('.nav').append(function(i,v){

    //use index of each .nav index starts at zero so if you need to start at 1 add 1 to index
    return $('<div id=example_'+i+'>example_'+i+'</div>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">

</div>
<div class="nav">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the authentic answer, I tested it myself.
You can use something like this if you are not adding simple html strings. First make the example a jQuery object, if it is not one already. Then you can easily manipulate the attributes.

```
var $example = $(example),
    idPre = 'example_',
    count = 1;
$(".nav").each(function() {
    $(this).append($example.clone().attr('id', idPre + count));
    count++;
});
```